# How do I turn a div Id into a class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am coding a website that will detect whether the user is on a mac or pc.  I have been able to get it to work as an ID but when I try it as a class it doesnt work. Could anyone please help.

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
function func1()
{
  var x = navigator.platform;

  if (x == "Win32" )
  {
    document.getElementsByClassName("pcbrowser").style.display = "block";
  } 
  else if (x == "MacIntel")
  {
    document.getElementById("macbrowser").style.display = "block";
  }
}

window.onload=func1

</script>


<span id="macbrowser" style="display:none">MAC</>
<span id="pcbrowser" style="display:none">Yosemite Backup Agent</p>
```

Comment: Your HTML is a little problematic: as far as I know, you can't have empty elements with attributes assigned. Just typing `< id="">` won't work, you have to declare a `<div>` or something similar. Also, you need quotes on the first `id`.

Answer (score 4):

The `getElementsByClassName` returns a HTMLCollection with ALL of the elements with this class, so you have to take the first element of this HTMLCollection (`getElementsByClassName('pcbrowser')[0]`)

Or you can use the `document.querySelector('.pcbrowser')` to get the element, the dot '.' stands for class. This shouldn't be done if the site has to work on old browsers, since its only compatible since IE8.

Answer (score 1):

The function is called `getElementsByClassName()` (plural "Elements") for a reason: it returns a `NodeList`, not a single element. (It's an "HTMLCollection", in particular.)

If there's definitely exactly one such element, then:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("pcbrowser")[0].style.display = "block";
```

Otherwise you can iterate through the NodeList more or less as if it were an array. Not *exactly* as if it were an array; if you're planning on making changes to the elements involved, then things can get weird because that API returns a NodeList that's "live" — it dynamically reflects the state of the DOM. You can copy its contents into a plain array, however:

```
var array = [].slice.call( theNodeList, 0 );
```

Comment: To be exact, [gEBCN()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), which  slightly differs from [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Comment: @Teemu ok I'm pretty much a slob about terminology :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("pcbrowser");
for (var i=0, item; i<elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example ...

The HTML ...

```
<p id="pcbrowser" class="pc" style="display:none">Yosemite Backup Agent</p>
<p id="macbrowser" class="mac" style="display:none">MAC</p>
```

The JavaScript ...

```
// anonymous function that runs automatically
(function() {

switch (navigator.platform) {

  case 'Win32':
    // use one of these methods
    var p = document.getElementById('pcbrowser'); // by id
    var p = document.querySelector('#pcbrowser'); // by id, slower than above
    var p = document.querySelector('.pc'); // by class, only the first element with that class
    var p = document.getElementsByClassName('pc')[0]; // by class, only the first element with that class

    // change the style if found
    if (p) {
      p.style.display = 'block';
    }
    break;

  case 'MacIntel':
    // use one of these methods
    var p = document.getElementById('macbrowser'); // by id
    var p = document.querySelector('#macbrowser'); // by id, slower than above
    var p = document.querySelector('.mac'); // by class, only the first element with that class
    var p = document.getElementsByClassName('mac')[0]; // by class, only the first element with that class

    // change the style if found
    if (p) {
      p.style.display = 'block';
    }  
    break;
}

})();
```

Good luck :)

Comment: thanks so but I need to add the class to multiple <p> tags. How do I do that.

Comment: I understood that you wanted to use class (or ID) to locate the element and change its style. Do you need to add/change its class?
If you mean to change the class of the element, that is also possible.

After getting the element (from one of the mentioned methods), you can change its class. Example:

`element.className = 'newClassName';`